# A Few Questions About Label Tags

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionview

1. How can I make the text displayed by a label tag bold?
2. I want two labels for the same tag, the second directly below the first. What's a good way to do this?
3. How can I choose the size of the text of the label?

Sorry if some of these are obvious, the documentation wasn't so helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Sample Image with more details will be helpful to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably make a class that sets the `font-weight` and `font-size` in it and then use that in your f.label's class.

For example, in your CSS, you have:

```
.mylabel {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

And then inside your html.erb, you'd have the css class you just made in it, like so...

```
<%= f.label :first_name, class: 'mylabel' %>:
```